# mb_strtolower not working

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-replace

I have the following string:

```
$var = "RUA TANGARA"
```

And I'm doing:

```
echo mb_strtolower(preg_replace('/[^~\'"]/', null, iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $var)), 'UTF-8');
```

But this still returning `"RUA TANGARA"`.

I use the `preg_replace()` because `$var` can be `"RÜÁ TÃNAGARA"`.

Can someone help me?

Comment: what does `preg_replace('/[^~\'"]/` have to do with this?

Comment: Well for one it's replacing all character in `$var` with `null`, so an empty string.

Comment: @AbraCadaver so it's a *trick* question then.

Comment: Did the preg_replace because this string can be `RÜÁ TÃNAGARA`

Comment: ...oh, so it gets better. Well you didn't include that bit in the original question.

Comment: Try using `echo mb_strtolower(preg_replace('/[^~\'"]/u', null, $var), 'UTF-8');` instead of using `iconv`. With the `u` modificator all string parameters are treated as UTF-8: http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you want to replace certain characters after the transliteration but you specified `^` (which has special meaning and means NOT) at the beginning of the character class `[]`.

So you are replacing characters that are NOT `~'"` (which happens to be all of them in your example), so it results in an empty string.  To fix, just escape the `^`, move it away from the beginning or remove it if not needed and it should be fine:

```
/[\^~\'"]/
```

Or:

```
/[~^\'"]/
```

[Working Example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/60d7293db7a0a5f99a7de3429cf954e9d6657eaf)

Answer (score 1):

PHP's functions work very well, take a look at this simple demonstration:

```
<?php
$data = "RUA TANGARA";
$result = mb_strtolower($data);
var_dump($result);
```

The obvious output is:

> string(11) "rua tangara"

---

The same works with non ascii characters:

```
<?php
$data = 'RÜÁ TÃNAGARA';
$result = mb_strtolower($data);
var_dump($result);
```

The output of that is:

> string(15) "rüá tãnagara"

Comment: This definitely works. I tested it before posting. Question is why it does not work _for you_. Maybe the multi byte string functions are not installed in your php environment? Please check your https server error log file if you use php inside such server and not via CLI.

Comment: I don't know how to check this, but, this is probably my problem because `preg_replace('/[.,]/', '', "11.704-600")` is not working too.

Comment: If you have shell access to your server an the problem appears in the CLI environment you can try `php -r 'echo mb_strtolower ("May BE some Text!\n");'`

Comment: Well, are the `preg` functions installed? That is a php extension? You _definitely_ want to check your http servers error log file.

Comment: The preg is installed because i'm using it in other functions. The thing is if i use `str_replace(".", "", "11.704-600")`, it doesn´t work too. BTW, i'm using laravel 5.3, PHP 7.1.2

Comment: Ok, then tell us: what does "is not working too" mean _exactly_?

Comment: @arkascha `preg_replace('/[.,]/', '', "11.704-600")`, `str_replace(".", "", "11.704-600")` returns me `11.704-600`

Comment: So not only the `mb_...()` and `preg_...()` functions, but also normal `str_...()` functions do nothing at all for you without throwing any error or warning what so ever? May we ask what php environment you are using and _how_ you test all that?

Comment: @IvanMoreira what doest that ^ have to do with your original question? Edit: I was referring to their comment, not yours arkascha.

Comment: @Fred-ii-, maybe nothing, i'm just desperate because this two functions are not working just in this file.

Comment: @Fred-ii- You refer to the overall depressed vibes in that scene? For that I prefer one of my favorites: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u7Dg3LrhmIY&index=4&list=PLmINM-vgFbqnIkMofU2YB3nsC2SaPcT5w The orchestration is unbelievable. Those dudes rock.

Comment: @IvanMoreira Is there a reason why you don't answer to any questions about your error log file, php setup or test scenario?

Comment: @arkascha Because there is nothing on error.log file, it's not an error, the php just ignore me.

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
$newStr = strtolower($var);

echo $newStr;
```